# Is it possible to add some information to the project to be built from QueueTaskDispatcher?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

QueueTaskDispatcher decides if some project could be started.
But I need not only decide if some project could be started, but also decide with what custom parameters it should be started.
And start project only then when it will be possible to set all custom parameters.
Is it possible to do such configuration of the project from QueueTaskDispatcher?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add Actions to Queue.Item that you get. If you want to tweak the parameters of the build, look for ParametersAction and you can fiddle with it.